# React + Map + Button doesn't work

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, dictionary

Basic functionality.

1. Print a list **DONE**
2. Adding a button to each list **DONE**
3. Button call a particular function. **NOW WORKING!!!**

> **THANKS ALL OF YOU GUYS!** - 
>   30/10/2017 - I found solution. In the end of const renderItems, I just added a simple this and works. of course, I forgot in this sample to add this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); on constructor. So now, is working to me

I already did research about it, and the best solution that I found was here: But every time that I try to use this guide: https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

But I always get the error:

> **Uncaught TypeError:** Cannot read property 'handleClick' of undefined

and I can't understand why. What I did (or doing) wrong?

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from 'axios';

class myApp extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            repos: []
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this); // ADDED
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        var $this = this;
        var URL = JSON;

        axios.get(URL).then(function(res) {
            $this.setState({
                repos: res.data
            });
        })
        .catch(function(e) {
            console.log("ERROR ", e);
        });
    }

  handleClick() {
        console.log('this is:', this);
  }

  render() {
      const renderItems = this.state.repos.map(function(repo, i) {
          return <li
                    key={i}>
                    <a onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(e)} >Click here!</a>
                    <span className='repoName'>
                        {repo.full_name}
                    </span>
                    <hr />
              </li>
      }, this); // just added THIS!

    return (

        <ul>
              {renderItems}
        </ul>
        <section className='target'>
              Target
        </section>
    );
  }
}

export default myApp;
```

Comment: it's a very common "context issue", you need to bind this (class context) with map callback function or use arrow function like this: `this.state.repos.map((repo, i) => {`

Comment: Lamba's can introduce a binding method so you don't have to fall into this `this` trap

Comment: I found solution. 
In the end of `const renderItems`, I just added a simple `this` and works. 

of course, I forgot in this sample to add `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);` on **constructor**. So now, is working to me.

Answer (score 0):

You get an undefined error because you have a missing parameter `e` in your method definition. `handleClick()` without a parameter has a different identity than `handleClick(e)`.

Bind `handleClick` in your constructor: `this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);`

Then change the `onClick` prop to `onClick={this.handleClick}`. Never use arrow functions inside the `render` function, this creates new identities of the function on every re-render which is bad practice and might cause performance issues as your application grows.

You can also use the experimental `public class fields syntax`, then you can define your click handler like so;

```html
handleClick = (e) => {
  // Stuff
}
```

Like this, you don't need to do any binding and you can just put `this.handleClick` in your `onClick` prop.

Answer (score 0):

Your `this` inside of `(e) => this.handleClick(e)` is not class `this`. Just do it this way `onClick={this.handleClick}`.This way you will have click event inside `this` in `handleClick` function. If you want class `this` inside `handleClick`, than do it `this.handleClick.bind(this)`